# WebDriver.io: how to make browser pause/ wait?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

For testing, I am loading a page and clicking a button, I am using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io) for testing Since the page is quite heavy, it takes a bit of time to load, I would like the global variable `browser` to wait few seconds before clicking the button.

I know there is `waitForVisible` method, but not good enough, I still have no idea if the js has added click event to the button, I am looking for something similar to `sleep` method in selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking about the [`pause()` method](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/pause/):

> pauses queue execution for a specific amount of time

Answer (score 2):

Since using [`pause()`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/pause/) is not a good practice, you can use [`waitForExist()`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForExist/) as an alternative